# Stack Corruption With SetupDiXxx structures

Tags: c++, windows-8, device-driver, hid

I am having some trouble with the structures used to obtain device information. From what I understand it is somewhat tricky to set the cbSize correctly, and thus the API is writing data beyond where it is supposed to (causing the stack corruption). So far I have the following code:

```
GUID guid;
HidD_GetHidGuid(&guid);

HDEVINFO info;
info = SetupDiGetClassDevs(&guid, NULL, NULL, DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE);

SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData;

memset(&DeviceInfoData, 0, sizeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA));
DeviceInfoData.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA);


int deviceIndex = 0;
while (SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(info, deviceIndex++, &DeviceInfoData))
{
    SP_INTERFACE_DEVICE_DATA data;
    data.cbSize = sizeof(SP_INTERFACE_DEVICE_DATA);

    int interfaceIndex = 0;


    while (SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(info, &DeviceInfoData, &guid, interfaceIndex++, &data))
    {

        //https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551120%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
        //Get the required buffer size. Call SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail with a NULLDeviceInterfaceDetailData pointer, 
        //a DeviceInterfaceDetailDataSize of zero, and a valid RequiredSize variable. In response to such a call, this function
        //returns the required buffer size at RequiredSize and fails with GetLastError returning ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER.

        SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA interfaceData;
        interfaceData.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA);

        DWORD bufferSize = 0;
        SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(info, &data, NULL, 0, &bufferSize, nullptr);

        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
        {
            //Call the function again
            SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(info, &data, &interfaceData, bufferSize, NULL, &DeviceInfoData);

            DWORD error = GetLastError();
            if (error != ERROR_SUCCESS)
            {
                printf("Could not obtain device interface details. Error: %d \n", error);
            }
        }
    }
```

The error which I get is:

```
    Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'DeviceInfoData' was corrupted.
```

though I have seen `SP_INTERFACE_DEVICE_DATA` and `SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA` cause the same error

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This isn't the error but if you are going to memset things I suggest you use `sizeof (DeviceInfoData)` ie the variable directly, so if its type ever changes, it will still work. You can also try `SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData = {};`

Comment: You retrieve the necessary buffer size on the first call, but pass it to the second call *without actually allocating that space*.  You're lying to the API about how much space is available, so it really isn't the APIs fault that it is overwriting the stack.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your `interfaceData` buffer is too small.

Check [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551120%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the `DeviceInterfaceDetailData` argument to `SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail` again.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get more info about driver development, I recommend the book `USB Complete`. I fixed the issue based on their explanation. The issue is as follows:

First, get the buffer size:

```
SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(info, &data, NULL, 0, &bufferSize, nullptr);
```

Then, allocate the `PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA` structure manually using malloc based on the size that was returned:

```
PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA interfaceData;
interfaceData->cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA);
```

notice the `P` in front of `PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA`. This is Microsofts semantics for this API. It stands for pointer; something really easy to miss when looking at the documentation (if you also miss the `->`)

The `SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail` function returns the size of the entire structure, so you need to allocate it to that size. I've seen examples that attempt to increment size until the error goes away. That approach is wrong... for alot of reasons. Obtain the size from `SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail` and then allocate the entire `PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA` memory block based on that size. Don't forget to set cbSize to the size of the struct `SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA`

Once again, pay attention to the `P` in the naming conventions because it's easy to get the `sizeof(PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA)` by mistake.

Comment: To be rigorous, since the data you're querying might change after you retrieve the size and before you get the data, you should check for ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER on the second call, and reallocate and loop if necessary.  But the risk of this happening is so low that many people don't bother.

Comment: More importantly, the code you show writes into a buffer that hasn't been allocated yet!